# room pragma query

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, android-room

How can I execute sql PRAGMA statement with Room database?

Why this statement doesn't work?

```
database.openHelper.readableDatabase.query("PRAGMA wal_checkpoint")
```

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem and found the solution was to check the result of the query.
I just checked the first column int which will be 1 if the the parameter is FULL, RESTART or TRUNCATE and the call is blocked ([see this.](https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_wal_checkpoint)).

```
Cursor c = room.query(new SimpleSQLiteQuery("pragma wal_checkpoint(full)"));
if(c.moveToFirst() && c.getInt(0) == 1)
    throw new RuntimeException("Checkpoint was blocked from completing");
```

Answer (score 0):

> How can I execute sql PRAGMA statement with Room database?

You could override the **init** method of the @Database class, and perform pragmas (or other database actions where you want to bypass Room's control) prior to the configuration.

e.g. :-

```
@Override
public void init(@NonNull DatabaseConfiguration configuration) {
    doPreRoomOpenStuff(configuration);
    super.init(configuration);
}

private void doPreRoomOpenStuff(DatabaseConfiguration dbconfig) {
    String dbpath = (dbconfig.context).getDatabasePath(DBNAME).getPath();
    if (ifDBExists(dbpath)) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(dbpath, null,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        Cursor csr = db.rawQuery("PRAGMA wal_checkpoint",null);
        while (csr.moveToNext()) {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            for (int c = 0; c < csr.getColumnCount(); c++) {
                sb.append("\n\tColumnName = ").append(csr.getColumnName(c)).append(" Value=").append(csr.getString(c));
            }
            Log.d("INFO",sb.toString());
        }
        db.close();
    }
}

private boolean ifDBExists(String dbpath) {
    File db = new File(dbpath);
    if(db.exists()) return true;
    File dir = new File(db.getParent());
    if (!dir.exists()) {
        dir.mkdirs();
    }
    return false;
}
```

Example result :-

```
06-18 18:22:14.244 1875-1875/? D/INFO:  ColumnName = busy Value=0
        ColumnName = log Value=-1
        ColumnName = checkpointed Value=-1
```

> Why this statement doesn't work?

I'm not sure, but I think it's down to Room being quite controlling.